# VBA Code "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to take all the fields in TBLCommissionTransactions in current DB and make a new table in T:\folder\TblBackups.mdb and append today’s date and time to the new table name. This is purely for archival purposes.

Sorry, not really well versed in VBA. I have the following code which I modified from search online. When I run it I get the message "Query input must contain at least one table or query" which I am suspecting is failing on strTableName but don't really know for sure. I have played around with it and can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub BackupTblCommissions_Click()
Dim strTableName As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strSQL As String
strFilename = "T:\folder\TblBackups.mdb"
strTableName = "TBLCommissionTransactions" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhmm")
strSQL = "SELECT TBLCommissionTransactions.* INTO " & strTableName & " IN " & _
strFilename & " FROM TBLCommissionTransactions;"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to make sure "strSQL" is concatenating the entire script?  Not sure the ampersand (&) will work prior to the line-continuation character. Maybe move it down prior to the "strFilename."

Answer (score 3):

You are missing some braces and quotes:

```
SELECT TBLCommissionTransactions.* 
INTO [TBLCommissionTransactions20120405-0054] IN 'T:\folder\TblBackups.mdb' 
FROM TBLCommissionTransactions;
```

So

```
strFilename = "'T:\folder\TblBackups.mdb'"
strTableName = "[TBLCommissionTransactions" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhmm" & "]")
strSQL = "SELECT TBLCommissionTransactions.* INTO " & strTableName & " IN " & _
strFilename & " FROM TBLCommissionTransactions;"
```